# Can Nepalese citizens residing abroad enter India without a visa?

Tags: visas, india, nepali-citizens

I am a Nepalese citizen living in Melbourne. I have to travel to India for 40 days. My question is, do I have to get a visa to travel to India as I'm currently living in Melbourne? I have my Nepalese citizenship and passport.

Answer (score 23):

No, you do not need a visa. Nepali citizens [may visit, work, and reside in India without restriction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-Nepal_Treaty_of_Peace_and_Friendship), and this does not change just because you plan to fly from Australia.